# (Windows) In Java, how can I write a program that I can open files with?

Tags: java, windows, file

I'm writing a custom text editor in Java that will eventually be compiled into a JAR or EXE. What code do I have to write in order to be able to open files with the program, such as right clicking a `file.txt -> open with -> mytexteditor.jar`? When writing the program, how do I allow opening files in this manner? I know how to create and work with `File` objects in general, but how do I get a `File` object when I open a text file using my program in this way?

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10, and I don't much mind if the solution only works on Windows.

Comment: This is very operating system dependent, and less directly related to Java

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you, I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. To me there are 2 steps: 1) create the application that can be started by passing a file name to the application 2) register your application with the OS. Not sure what step your question is about. Step 1 should be easy enough as you would just receive a String representing the file. You then create the File object using the string and start your application. Have no idea how to do step 2 in Java.

Comment: @camickr Yeah I get step 1, it's step 2 where I'm lost.

Comment: [Possible solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+register+my+program+with+file+type+windows+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Passing one file to any other application is controlled by DDE (Dynamic Data Excehange). You need to write an OS level program for it. Read more for [DDE.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/win32/dataxchg/about-dynamic-data-exchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely check this out and accept this if it turns out to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Nick: this is not correct if all you're trying to is to associate a file type with your application.